# How to increase VNC server frame rate when using libvncserver library?

Tags: performance, vnc, vnc-server

I am currently (slowly) going through the [libvncserver doc](http://libvncserver.sourceforge.net/doc/html/libvncserver_doc.html) but I can't find what field or function to call where I can increase the server's frame rate.

By frame rate, I mean how fast the server sends display updates to the connected client(s). Assume there are no limits for the CPU/RAM/network resources on the server.